# PermissionDenied: Zugriff verweigert (os error 5) when installing snel via deno

Tags: deno

everytime I try to install Snel with this command `deno run -A https://deno.land/x/snel/install.ts`, I get the error message:

```
PermissionDenied: Zugriff verweigert (os error 5)
    at Object.opSync (deno:core/01_core.js:149:12)
    at opRun (deno:runtime/js/40_process.js:27:17)
    at Object.run (deno:runtime/js/40_process.js:114:17)
    at install (https://deno.land/x/snel@v0.6.0/install.ts:18:24)
    at Main (https://deno.land/x/snel@v0.6.0/install.ts:32:9)
    at https://deno.land/x/snel@v0.6.0/install.ts:37:3
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMhYM.png)

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Edit: I have Admin rights and used the https://github.com/crewdevio/Snel manual, so this is not the issue.

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/crewdevio/Snel? Did you try `deno run --allow-run --allow-read https://deno.land/x/snel/install.ts`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I read the GitHub and 'deno run --allow-run --allow-read https://deno.land/x/snel/install.ts' I also tried. But the same error appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: The problem was, that there was a space in the `Deno.execPath()`.
The Deno Community could fix the issue in the Snel installing script.
The new version can handle spaces and already got merged.

Answer (score 0):

According to
https://github.com/crewdevio/Snel#what-do-i-need-to-start-using-snel

-->

```sh
deno run --allow-run --allow-read https://deno.land/x/snel/install.ts
```

I would assume your statement should work. Is it possible that you do not have admin rights on your machine?

Comment: Thank you for your response. This should not be the problem, as my user has admin rights and I opened the terminal with admin rights.

Answer (score -1):

As a plan B you might want to post this link in the Deno Community:
https://discord.com/invite/deno

Comment: Thank you! The Deno Community could solve my issue.